# Convert 2D projections to 3D View in AutoCAD

Tags: drafting, autocad

Suppose I have three 2D drawings prepared in AutoCAD LT.

That 2D drawings are supposed to represent *top*, *left* and *front* projections of the 3D solid body.

How can I view that 3D solid body?

Comment: Are you looking for an automated method that uses any given projections?

Comment: I don't need to be flexible with projections themselves: top/bottom, left/right, front/rear projections, all perpendicular to each other. I want to avoid drawing in 3D. I would rather draw 2D drafts and combine them into 3D view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to watch these videos first:

[AutoCAD 2D to 3D Conversion Trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFSV47I7SBg)

[Learn how to take 2D drawing designs and ideas and turn them into 3D objects.](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-ECFB3220-6484-4D0B-BB7E-B06AD9F4E856-htm.html)

```
http://acronymonline.org/2d-flat-geometry-3d-autocad/
```

---

***Also:***

**How to Convert a 2D Model to 3D Using AutoCAD**

> by Darrin Koltow, studioD, `http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-2d-model-3d-using-autocad-31833.html`

Use AutoCAD's "Extrude" and "Revolve" commands to turn 2-D designs into 3-D models. "Extrude" is how 3-D modelers to refer to the technique of stretching a 2-D shape into 3-D space. AutoCAD performs this expansion by first extending a new axis at right angles to the 2-D axes on which your 2-D design sits. It then makes a copy of the 2-D shapes you are expanding at a higher location on the axis, while keeping the original shapes at the base of the axis. After converting your 2-D design to 3-D, display it with realistic lighting and shadows using the "Render" command on the Render tab.

**Step 1**

Click the "File" menu and select the "Open" command from the context menu. Navigate to an AutoCAD file with a 2-D model that you want to convert to 3-D and double-click on it. AutoCAD will load the file for you to convert.

**Step 2**

Type "Perspective 1" to indicate that you want to view your design with perspective, which means that parallel lines will appear to converge as they do in the physical world. This option is more realistic than parallel projection.

**Step 3**

Click the “cube” icon at the top right of the canvas and then drag the mouse until the top, right and front sides of the cube are visible. This changes the viewpoint from 2-D to 3-D, allowing you to see the three-dimensionality of the 3-D form that you'll create from the 2-D model.

**Step 4**

Click the drop-down list at the top of the application window, then click the "3-D modeling" item to change the workspace to one that displays tools for creating and editing 3-D objects. Click the "Home" tab to access the "Modeling" panel, which displays the "Extrude" tool for converting rectangular 2-D shapes into block-like 3-D forms.

**Step 5**

Click the "Extrude" button; then click a shape of your 2-D model that you want to turn into a block form, as opposed to a cylindrical or spherical form. Press "Enter." The shape you selected will expand into 3-D space and the top of the box formed from the shape will stick to your cursor. Drag the cursor until the box reaches the height you want, and then click the mouse to end the extrusion. Use the "Extrude" command on the remaining parts of the 2-D model that you want to expand into blocks.

**Step 6**

Click the "Surface" tab and go to the "Create" panel to find the "Revolve" command, which makes cylindrical, spherical and other round forms from 2-D shapes. Click this command, and then click a shape in your 2-D model that you want to convert to a cylinder or other round form. Type the axis around which you want to revolve the shape, which can be "x," "y," or "z." Press "Enter" to perform the revolution, then revolve the other parts of your design that you want to have round 3-D forms to complete the conversion of your 2-D design to a 3-D model.

Comment: video is quite to the point, thanks for posting that link. one have to have AutoCAD for doing similar conversions. Is it only possibility? I was thinking about AutoCAD LT as starting point and then some sort of viewer program...

Comment: I don't know any scripts about this issue, but you can try [one yourself](http://www.cad-notes.com/learn-how-to-write-command-scripts-for-autocad-and-automate-your-plotting/) or ask to the AutoCAD forums. Hope someone helps :)